# .Include() vs .Load() performance in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When querying a large table where you need to access the navigation properties later on in code (I explicitly don't want to use lazy loading) what will perform better `.Include()` or `.Load()`? Or why use the one over the other?

In this example the included tables all only have about 10 entries and employees has about 200 entries, and it can happen that most of those will be loaded anyway with include because they match the where clause.

```
Context.Measurements.Include(m => m.Product)
                    .Include(m => m.ProductVersion)
                    .Include(m => m.Line)
                    .Include(m => m.MeasureEmployee)
                    .Include(m => m.MeasurementType)
                    .Where(m => m.MeasurementTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                    .ToList();
```

or

```
Context.Products.Load();
Context.ProductVersions.Load();
Context.Lines.Load();
Context.Employees.Load();
Context.MeasurementType.Load();

Context.Measurements.Where(m => m.MeasurementTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

### It depends, try both

When using `Include()`, you get the **benefit** of loading all of your data in a single call to the underlying data store. If this is a remote SQL Server, for example, that can be a major performance boost.

The **downside** is that `Include()` queries tend to get *really* **complicated**, especially if you have any filters (`Where()` calls, for example) or try to do any grouping. EF will generate very heavily nested queries using sub-`SELECT` and `APPLY` statements to get the data you want. It is also much less efficient -- you get back a single row of data with every possible child-object column in it, so data for your top level objects will be repeated a lot of times. (For example, a single parent object with 10 children will product 10 rows, each with the same data for the parent-object's columns.) I've had single **EF queries get so complex they caused deadlocks** when running at the same time as EF update logic.

The `Load()` method is much **simpler**. Each query is a single, easy, straightforward `SELECT` statement against a single table. These are much easier in every possible way, *except* you have to do many of them (possibly many times more). If you have nested collections of collections, you may even need to loop through your top level objects and `Load` their sub-objects. It can get out of hand.

### Quick rule-of-thumb

Try to **avoid** having any **more than three `Include` calls** in a single query. I find that EF's queries get too ugly to recognize beyond that; it also matches my rule-of-thumb for SQL Server queries, that up to four JOIN statements in a single query works very well, but after that it's time to *consider refactoring*.

However, all of that is only a starting point.

**It depends on your schema, your environment, your data**, and many other factors.

In the end, you will just need to **try it out each way**.

*Pick a reasonable "default" pattern to use, see if it's good enough, and if not, optimize to taste.*

Comment: +1 for taking the network connection into account (_If this is a remote SQL Server_). It's often a major point to consider.

Comment: +1 - try both. in my use-case `Include()` took 7 minutes, `Load()` took 1.9 seconds and used less RAM. I added `LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: Excellent answer. Only thing to add is that I have just been through this exercise and in my (particular) case we found performance with both to be unacceptable. I used AutoMapper's ProjectTo (QueryableExtension) and a new v. simple DTO / POCO to effectively control the SQL EF generated. I have my query running now in 1/20th of the time. Thanks JBogard ! http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 24):

`Include()` will be written to SQL as `JOIN`: one database roundtrip.

Each `Load()`-instruction is "explicitly loading" the requested entities, so one database roundtrip per call.

Thus `Include()` will most probably be the more sensible choice in this case, but it depends on the database layout, how often this code is called and how long your `DbContext` lives. Why don't you try both ways and profile the queries and compare the timings?

See [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

Comment: Your explanation is right, but `Include()` won't necessarily be the more sensible choice. Depending on the concrete table definitions, and the database used, the query with so many includes may become so complex that it performs far worse than separate queries with `Load()`. (Yes, I've had that happen.)

Comment: @hvd agreed, that can happen, though I don't find five joins many. The real answer would be: _"Measure it"_ anyway, as we don't know anything about OP's database.

Comment: Late in the game here but Load is NOT explicitly loading related entities.  You use explicit loading in code in order to give you granular control over your related entities using either the Collection or Reference keyword.  Using Load in serialization scenarios, such as returning JSON from a controller, could cause a scenario where all your entities get loaded recursively.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with @MichaelEdenfield in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19319663/81595) but I did want to comment on the nested collections scenario. You can get around having to do nested loops (and the many resulting calls to the database) by turning the query inside out.

Rather than loop down through a Customer's Orders collection and then performing another nested loop through the Order's OrderItems collection say, you can query the OrderItems directly with a filter such as the following.

```
context.OrderItems.Where(x => x.Order.CustomerId == customerId);
```

You will get the same resulting data as the Loads within nested loops but with just a single call to the database.

Also, there is a special case that should be considered with Includes. If the relationship between the parent and the child is one to one then the problem with the parent data being returned multiple times would not be an issue.

I am not sure what the effect would be if the majority case was where no child existed - lots of nulls? Sparse children in a one to one relationship might be better suited to the direct query technique that I outlined above.

Answer (score 5):

`Include` is an example of eager loading, where as you not only load the entities you are querying for, but also all related entities.

`Load` is an manual override of the `EnableLazyLoading`. If this one is set to `false`. You can still lazily load the entity you asked for with `.Load()`

Comment: this explains the difference which is great, but the question was asking about performance

Comment: Load is NOT a manual override of EnableLazyLoading.  If you set it to false, you must use Explicit Loading with either the Collection or Reference keywoard.  See http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/explicit-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It's always hard to decide whether to go with Eager, Explicit or even Lazy Loading.
What I would recommend anyway is always to perform some profiling. That's the only way to be sure your request will be performant or not.
There're a lot of tools that will help you out. Have a look at [this article from Julie Lerman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx) where she lists several different ways to do profiling. One simple solution is to start [profiling in your SQL Server Management Studio](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799.aspx).
Do not hesitate to talk with a DBA (if you have on near you) that will help you to understand the execution plan.
You could also have a look a [this presentation](https://techblog.betclicgroup.com/2013/10/08/entity-framework-training/) where I wrote a section about loading data and performance.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing to add to this thread. It depends on what server you use. If you are working on sql server it's ok to use eager loading but for sqlite you will have to use .Load() to avoid crossloading exception cause sqlite can not deal with some include statements that go deeper than one dependency level

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: As of EF Core 5.0 you can use `AsSplitQuery()`.

This is particularly useful and I personally use it all the time when I have many joins
which will result in a possible cartesian explosion, or will just take more time to complete.

As the name implies, EF will execute separate queries for each Entity instead of using joins.

So, where you would use Explicit loading, you can now use Eager loading with split queries to achieve the same result, and it's definitely more readable imo.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries