# Select from multiple tables based upon search term but good in performance

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq

I have a query in which I pass the search term to filter the list of `Companies`, either by `Email` or company `Title` which is stored in another table (`TranslationTexts`) as `Text` column for multiple locales.

The query runs fine but it is very heavy and takes time. How can I make it more efficient?

[**See Table Diagram Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Md13.png)

The query:

```
gm.ListData = context.Companies.ToList()
                     .Where(a => a.AspNetUser.Email.NullableContains(searchTerm) ||
                                 a.TitleTranslation.TranslationTexts
                                  .Where(b => b.Text.NullableContains(searchTerm)).Any()
                    ).Select(c => new ListCompany
                    {
                        CompanyID = c.CompanyID,
                        EmailID = c.AspNetUser.Email,
                        Title = c.TitleTranslation.TranslationTexts.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Locale == Locale).Text
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Try making a View and query against it or the alternate would be to use Include to prevent lazy loading and it behaves like joins instead of inner queries. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19319663/1433093 and http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/eager-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: What is this `NullableContains` method?

Comment: The first call to `ToList` (`Companies.ToList`) retrieves all the companies in the database, causing the `Where` query to be run on the in-memory collection rather than on the database. This will generally be slower than having the `Where` run on the database instead. Try removing the first call to `ToList`. In addition, try including the `TranslationTexts` from the get-go (`Companies.Include(c => c.TitleTranslation.TranslationTexts).Where`).

Comment: The NullableContains is a custom extension method which handles the string finding logic. As it is not a store expression that is why i have to call ToList on the context before i can use the extension method. I know it retrieves all the companies records then does further query, but i need to call the extension method. 
How can i create the views using Linq?

Comment: The key is to turn into an expression what you do in `NullableContains`. So, what does it do?

Comment: the NullableContains code. public static bool NullableContains(this string text, string searchTerm)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return text.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        }