# What is the difference between load and include in sql query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a query that looks like this

```
         var query = db.Customer
            .Include(c => c.Address)
            .Where(c => c.Address.Id > 10)
            .ToList();
```

when i do this instead

```
        var query = db.Customer
            .Where(c => c.Address.Id > 10)
            .ToList();

        db.Address
            .Where(a => a.Id > 10)
            .Load();
```

I get the same result as far as I see.

My question is: is there any difference between what these two queries return and is one preferred over the other?

Comment: Have you tried to search for duplicates "load vs include"? There are plenty, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19319116/1997232).

Comment: I did, but obviously not good enough. But this case is slightly different, since I use Address in the first query before I Load it I wanted to know if this could cause any problem or the result of both methods would always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = db.Customer
                .Include(c => c.Address)
                .Where(c => c.Address.Id > 10)
                .ToList();
```

On above query where it brings all the related data using single database trip.

```
 var query = db.Customer
                .Where(c => c.Address.Id > 10)
                .ToList();

            db.Address
                .Where(a => a.Id > 10)
                .Load();
```

Here it uses 2 database trips to bring the data.

[**Load :**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592911(v=vs.113).aspx)

> There are several scenarios where you may want to load entities from
>   the database into the context without immediately doing anything with
>   those entities. A good example of this is loading entities for data
>   binding as described in Local Data. One common way to do this is to
>   write a LINQ query and then call ToList on it, only to immediately
>   discard the created list. The Load extension method works just like
>   ToList except that it avoids the creation of the list altogether.

**Note :** We cannot say which one is better.Most of the time we use eager loading method (`Include`).It is nice and simple.But sometimes it is slow.So you need to decide which one to use according to your data size and etc.

Comment: So both queries bring back the exact same data then? my code is a little bit different than this and when I look in SQL server profiler the first query has a little bit more reads than the second one, is that a good indication on which query I should use?

Also you said the include method was eager loading, does the load method also have a name?

Comment: which one is the fast ?