# Linq2db: join tables with eager loading

Tags: c#, linq2db

I'm using linq2db ORM in my project and have the following database schema (simplified):

[image]

I have the following method to get information about the user:

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(int id)
{
  var user =
    await (
        from u in _db.Users
                     .LoadWith(u => u.Accounts)
                     .ThenLoad(a => a.Transactions)
        where u.Id == id
        from lang in _db.Languages.LeftJoin(l => l.Id == u.LanguageId)
        select u)
      .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

  return user;
}
```

However, I wanted to get the information about all the limits and aggregators for each account. I believe there should be an efficient way to do that. Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we use `LoadWith()`, after using `ThenLoad()`, it's going to start from the root (`User` table), like this:

```
from u in _db.Users
                 .LoadWith(u => u.Accounts)
                    .ThenLoad(a => a.Transactions)
                 .LoadWith(u => u.Accounts)
                    .ThenLoad(a => a.Limits)
                 .LoadWith(u => u.Accounts)
                    .ThenLoad(a => a.Aggregators);
```

> You can also use `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` instead of `LoadWith()` and `ThenLoad()`. [Include vs Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319116/include-vs-load-performance-in-entityframework).

Comment: I cannot use Inlucde, linq2db and EF are different ORM, and Include() is used in EF.

Comment: However, your approach gave me a useful hint, and I could solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: You are right. I'm happy that it was useful to you.